# Saddle valve leaks t turn on

Tags: water, leaks, saddle-valve

Some months after I turned this saddle valve off I turned it back on. It leaked with increasing flow until it was **completely** turned on. Then it stopped.  Is this ok? Is it normal?  Or would I be wise to replace/repair the valve.

Answer (score 2):

Saddle valves are notorious for leaking and failing in just a few years. The best repair would be to install a T at the point the saddle valve is attached. This is something most DIY folks can do with plastic or copper pipe a bit more difficult if galvinised pipe. If you stay with a saddle valve get the best quality one you can find.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this OK?

**No**, you should replace the valve as soon as you have the chance, better yet would be to install a tee and regular stop-valve, preferably one of high quality.

> Is it normal?

It is fairly common for older valves to leak at the stem area until back-seated (or as you said, completely turned on).